# Can folders be shared between two guest OS (Ubuntu and Windows XP ) in VMPlayer

Tags: vmware-player, shared-folders

I have a machine with CentOS 6 and VMPlayer 5.x running Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04 guests. I am trying to find a way for the Windows XP and Ubuntu guests to share folders with each other.

Each guest is able to see shared folders from the host, but cannot see the folders of the other VM.

Is it possible to do this? I can always set up a system where the host has a folder that is shared in both Windows XP and Ubuntu, but I was hoping for a more direct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that they can be directly shared.

But the option you outlined is the most direct way to handle this feature you want, and it's one that businesses/enterprises use.

You could setup, if your guests are all participating in the same LAN, a network share on one of the guests (CIFS/SMB) and allow the other one access to it to mount it. But this is cumbersome and the overhead would diminish the speed.

Honestly having both guests access the same folder in your host would be the fastest way to do it.